Axios cannot handle binary response and returns 500
I have a middleware server build with nodejs. I use it to communicate with different APIs. One of the endpoints is to get a pdf file that comes in binary format like

%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<<
/CreationDate(D:20240703084315+00'00'

It was all good until I had to upgrade axios from v0.21.4 to v1.6.7. After this I start receiving errors like

AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500
code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE',

I did not changed anything about the request and the response, just upgraded the version
here is the request
   const options = {
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        data: bodyData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        
    }
await axios(options)

Executing the request for the pdf in postman works fine. If the axios is on the old version is working fine, but with the latest - it fails. What I'm doing wrong?
I have tried all suggestions found on internet but without any success. I'm out of ideas and options so any help will be highly appreciated.

What is the content type of your api endpoint

Of the response?
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
res.status(200).send(new Buffer.from(pdfData, 'binary'))
But it does not go to there at all. It is failing on the response from the api
